# App crashes whenever i click showing error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Tags: android, android-studio

The app is opening and working fine till I made a click Basically it is a Connect-3 game and on clicking it crashes.

My logcat is

```
    12-13 14:22:32.393 2482-2482/com.govinddixit.connect3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=8
                                                                                at com.govinddixit.connect3.MainActivity.dropIn(MainActivity.java:44)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  12-13 14:24:17.457 2482-2482/com.govinddixit.connect3 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2482 SI

G: 9

My java activity is

```
package com.govinddixit.connect3;

import android.media.Image;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.security.KeyStore;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    //0=yellow,1=red
    int activePlayer = 0;
    boolean gameisActive = true;
    //2 means unplayed
    int[] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};
    int[][] winningPosition = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};

    public void dropIn(View view) {
        ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;

        int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

        if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2 && gameisActive) {
            gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;

            counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);

            if (activePlayer == 0) {
                counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                activePlayer = 1;
            } else {
                counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                activePlayer = 0;
            }
            counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).rotation(36).setDuration(300);

            for (int[] winningPosition : winningPosition) {
                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
                        gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                        gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {
                    //someone has won//
                    gameisActive = false;

                    String winner = "RED";

                    if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0) {
                        winner = "YELLOW";


                        TextView winnerMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);
                        winnerMessage.setText("has won");

                        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);

                        layout.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);

                    } else {
                        boolean gameIsOver = true;

                        for (int counterState : gameState) {

                            if (counterState == 2) {
                                gameIsOver = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if (gameIsOver) {
                            TextView winnerMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);
                            winnerMessage.setText("It's a draw");

                            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);

                            layout.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void playAgain(View view)
    {
        gameisActive = true;
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
            layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            activePlayer= 0;

            for(int i=0;i<gameState.length;i++)
            {
               gameState[i]=2;
            }
            GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
            for(int i=0;i<gridLayout.getChildCount();i++)
            {
                ((ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);
            }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

My xml file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.govinddixit.connect3.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/playAgainLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingHorizontal="30dp"
        android:paddingVertical="30dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/winnerMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/playAgainButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="playAgain"
            android:text="PLAY AGAIN" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.496">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="0"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="149dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="0" />
    </GridLayout>

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=8 at MainActivity.dropIn(line 44)`.

Comment: where should I correct in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that part of your code:

```
for (int[] winningPosition : winningPosition) {
            if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {
```

so your are looping through:

```
int[][] winningPosition = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
```

then you take the ints in your 3-ints arrays as an index to look up the element in the other array:

```
int[] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};
```

but that array has **only 8 elements**!

So when you take the '8' from previous `winningPosition` array you would do `gameState[8]` which looks for the 9th element which not exists --> `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=8 at MainActivity.dropIn(line 44)`

Comment: I am beginner can u elaborate what should i do

Comment: the gamestate array is representing each field of the match 3 game? In that case it should probably contain 9 elements and not 8. (3 * 3 = 9 in my math)

Comment: sir, when I put 9 elements in the array the click run but for only once then app freezes

Comment: Yeah, but that is another problem not related to the array out of bounds. Better close this question and ask another question describing the new problem you have

Comment: No problem :-) Programming is a lot about trial and error and debugging, don't give up.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is within gamestate[winningPosition[2]]
it is refering to the third position winningposition array which is sometimes 8....the total length of gamestsate is also 8 which is causing the index out of range exception
I think adding another (2) to the array gamestate will solve the problem

Comment: He is shadowing the array of int arrays `winningPosition` in line 43 with another array of ints declaration here: `for (int[] winningPosition : winningPosition) {`

Comment: try to change one character of the variable name 

for example make it winingPosition or winningposition

Comment: Ahmed can u elaborate your answer

Comment: int[] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};
I just add another item of the value 2 to the array